# abstractor method with object return type in java

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class, abstract-methods

I'm new at oop ,I want to pass object parameter of an abstract method but it gives me error, can anyone explain it to me and help me fix the error .
Thanks for your help.

```
abstract class FunctionInt{
int num1;
int num2;

abstract FunctionInt test(FunctionInt newNum);

}

class Function extends FunctionInt{
public Function(int num1,int num2){
this.num1=num1;
this.num2=num2;
}
public Function (){

}

Function test(Function c){
return c;
}
```

Comment: You changed the signature of `test`. You can't do that and keep the contract. Also class names start with a capital letter. How is a `Function` different from a `FunctionInt`? Why is `FunctionInt` abstract? And what behavior are you trying to program?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch can you pls correct it for me , method test should return an object type how can I do this with abstract method?

Comment: Some Errors : Constructor name should be equal to class name 
and why making FunctionInt abstract

Comment: confused with OOPS Concepts??
I will help you check my profile and message me on instagram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the abstract method signature. You have created an entirely new method unrelated to the method you wanted to override. Use the `@Override` annotation to spot this class of errors more quickly.

```
public class Function extends FunctionInt {
    public Function(int num1, int num2) {
        this.num1 = num1;
        this.num2 = num2;
    }

    public Function() {

    }

    @Override
    FunctionInt test(FunctionInt c) {
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but it also gives me error ! because the FunctionInt is abstract

Comment: What error? This at least compiles.

Comment: I appreciate your help, thanks Its working now

Comment: @Basta Glad to hear it. Keep coding. The best way to learn is to do.